# swift 3 UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I'm a newbie.
But I do not understand why the UITableView was not all elements loads (10 element in array).
With Xcode7 works but with Xcode8 (Swift 3) no.
I rewrote the code but to no avail: one element is being loaded ...

This is the code inside the UIViewController (with extension UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource)

**CODE:**

```
// MARK: UITableView
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return commentArray.count
}

// cell height
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true  
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = mytableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellComment", for: indexPath ) as! commentCell


    // connect objects with our information from arrays
    cell.usernameBtn.setTitle(usernameArray[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)
    cell.usernameBtn.sizeToFit()
    cell.commentLbl.text = commentArray[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

I think the problem is in the `cellForRowAt....`
I also have the following error:

> `BFTask` caught an exception in the continuation block. This behaviour is discouraged and will be removed in a future release. Caught Exception: Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.

I do not understand.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 } Replace your this method with this one and check it

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya No, the OP has the correct method name for Swift 3.

Comment: Did you add tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40?                And did you set data source? tableView.dataSource = self?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use following lines inside CellForRowAt IndexPath:

```
let cellIdentifier = "CellComment"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell?
```

Comment: You don't explain the important part. The OP needs to change `mytableView` with `tableView`. There is no need to use the `cellIdentifier` constant.

Answer (score 0):

Changing mytableView to tableView inside cellForRowAt indexPath delegate method should solve the issue.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellComment", for: indexPath ) as! commentCell
```

Answer (score 0):

There can some problems in your code. Try resolving/checking the following possible mistakes :

1. According to your error the problem might be in the subscripting of your arrays. Try this:

   usernameArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

And also use the delegate:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}
```

2. remove estimatedHeightForRowAt and add the following code in viewDidLoad() function

   tableView?.estimatedRowHeight = 135 //This value should be nearest to your cell height.
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
3. you might not have set the delegates for tableViewDataSource and tableViewDelegate. Set the delegate from the storyboard or in viewDidLoad() method.